# Meaning of "Initial document committed to confluence"

Tags: meaning

[image]

What does the above highlighted phrase mean?

> Initial document committed to confluence

Comment: What does "confluence" mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "please cost both" mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350523/what-does-please-cost-both-mean)

Comment: See https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEVAL/Confluence%3A+Document+Management+System. "Confluence" is used for team collaboration, often in Agile environments. In this case, it is being used to save different versions of a document.

Comment: To make this post more useful, I suggest you change the title to something like: "What does 'Initial document committed into confluence' mean?" And no need to plead... we're a very friendly community.

Comment: As a rebuttal to the close- and down-votes, this is not a clear cut as it seems.  To those who are aware of the brand name collaboration tool from the Atlassian company, the meaning is obvious.  For everyone else reading this, the response might be, "why in the heck would one want the first draft of a written work to be invested at the point where multiple rivers meet?"

Comment: @cobaltduck - But one would quickly notice that this is referring to Revision 1.0, meaning this is the first appearance of this document, and thus it is being placed in whatever document management system is being used in the business.  Very likely this initial comment is "boilerplate" and was simply copied from the standard skeleton document.  It could say "Initial document microwaved for 15 minutes" and no one would really notice.

Answer (score 2):

[Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) is a team collaboration tool, often in Agile environments. In this case, it is being used to save different versions of a document.

The documentation cited should have capitalized the C in Confluence or perhaps written:

> Initial document committed to Atlassian Confluence.

Confluence may be used as a [Document Management System](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEVAL/Confluence%3A+Document+Management+System).

From that link:

> Confluence is an excellent solution to use as a document control system. It’s inbuilt abilities to manage, version, search and organize attachments for a few customers justify it as an end-to-end replacement for a shared document repository.

Answer (score 0):

It may be referring to this:

[Atlassian Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence?_mid=de75b90b1e9391a6b8fae5d1957b98a8&aceid=&adposition=1t1&adgroup=9509302921&campaign=183110161&creative=51299235961&device=c&keyword=confluence&matchtype=e&network=g&placement=&gclid=CKuU6sDDr88CFUVmGwodCkAJjg)

a team collaboration tool, with document management. The initial document may have been uploaded to this software.